# Test if shared folder exists with timeout in a batch file

Tags: networking, batch, shared-folders, timeout

I've been using the following command to test if a shared network folder exists: `if exist \\192.168.1.2\SharedFolder\ echo EXISTS` however when it does not exist it takes around 15 seconds for it to figure that out. Is there a way I could add a timeout to that command? I really only want it to try for three seconds.

Comment: No, it's OS timeout. OS tries to check the resource syncronously, so batch execution is freesed. And no way to set up any timeout for IF EXIST command.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check first if remote PC is alive then try to connect to it.

```
@echo off

REM Try for 3 seconds if remote PC is alive
ping 192.168.1.2 -n 2 -w 400 2>&1 >nul

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto OnExit
goto Success

:OnExit
echo 192.168.1.2 is down
goto End

:Success

echo Remote computer is alive. Checking if share is available...
IF EXIST \\192.168.1.2\SharedFolder\ (
    echo SharedFolder is available.
) ELSE (
    echo SharedFolder is unavailable.
)

:End
REM pause
```

Comment: The program I am using already determines live computers on the network. Only one of them has a shared folder though.

Comment: @MarkDodsons The point is to check if remote PC is alive just before trying for remote share availability. There no any mechanism to control timeout in `if exist \\ip.ip.ip.ip\Share` statement since it is operation system timeout. In my example I checking remote PC with `ping` utility where I can reduce timeout with option `-w` as you want and only after that checking for remote share.

Comment: Unfortunately this still does not solve my problem. Devices like printers or chromecasts for example, reply with ping but take forever with the if exist thing. Is there any third party tool that could help?

Comment: Most of the printers and chromecasts doesn't have capability to share resources over windows network. You can use network scanners such as [nmap](https://nmap.org/download.html) or [advanced-ip-scanner](https://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/) to be make sure those devices has windows sharing capability.

Comment: Rock that may work.